# How to make the @Html.EditorFor Disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
<div><span class="f">Data Center Name</span> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Switch.TMSRack.DataCenter.Name, new  { disabled = "disabled" })</div>
```

but the field will not be disabled ,, can anyone adivce please?
THanks

Comment: From MVC 5.1 onwards `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled= "disabled" }})`

Comment: If you are using asp core, I explained a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639822/6339469

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`@Html.EditorFor()` does not have an overload to support htmlAttributes. You could try `@Html.TextBoxFor()`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.propertyName, new {disabled= "disabled" })
```

If you are using system key words such as `class` in htmlAttributes please add `@` before the attribute name.

Ex:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.propertyName, new {@class = "disabledClass" })
```

Comment: worked with both class and TextBoxFor:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Doctor.Label1, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })

Comment: It's not that EditorFor doesn't support html attributes, it's that the viewModels it uses to display the controls don't support it.  You can add support in them.

Answer (score 42):

Using MVC 5, `@Html.EditorFor()` supports htmlAttributes

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.x, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
```

The above example shows how you can add a class and also the disabled attribute

Comment: how can I make the disabled attribute conditional?

Comment: You can use jQuery to add and remove the disabled attribute with if statements 
 $('.inputDisabled').prop("disabled", false); 
 $('.inputDisabled').prop("disabled", true);

Comment: @LuisBecerril you could do something like `if (@Model.IsReadOnly) { @Html.EditorFor(m => m.x, new { htmlAttributes = ... } else { @Html.EditorFor(m => m.x) }`.  You'll need a property on the view-model to indicate whether the control should be read-only.

Comment: Just worth mentioning, a disabled field value does not get pass through to the controller. Instead, you would use @readonly = "readonly"

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative: surround the EditorFor with a div or a span with a certain id, and then use a bit of jquery/js:

```
  <span id="editors">      
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ViewModelProperty)
  </span>

    <!-- Disable above editors. EditorFor doesn't allow html attributes unfortunately. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { $('#editors :input').attr("disabled", true); });
    </script>
```

Comment: Adding the Javascript part for my code's 'nop-editor' worked for me. 

`$('#DisplayOrderSection :input').attr("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 6):

For those that lose your text value : Disabled fields does not pass its value to the controller. Instead, use `@readonly = "readonly"`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control"} })
```

Answer (score 4):

If you lose information when you accept the Edit-changes ...
You could try

```
<h3>@Model.x</h3>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.x, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `EditorFor()`
eg:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nama, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled ="true", @class = "form-control" } })
```